# How to get latest data among two similar tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with same columns  one is like  **Vendor registration** and another is  **'Vendor Update'**  tables.  if any changes made in Vendor registration one row  created in   Vendor Update.i need data like  If there is no data in Vendor Update i need to show Vendor registration data if there is data in Vendor Update i need to show latest data  from   for A and B tables There is link like(A.id=B.Vid)

thanks in Advance

I tried each possible ways iam not getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f2sE.jpg)

Comment: Please avoid to explain everything in words only. Provide some sample data and the expected result as tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need show only latest data if its available in B I need show B else A

Use `UNION ALL` to join the tables (with a priority for each table) and then use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to find the first priority and latest date for each `id`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY priority, date_column DESC) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT b.id,
           b.date_column,
           b.column1,
           b.column2,
           1 AS priority
    FROM   b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.id,
           a.date_column,
           a.column1,
           a.column2,
           2 AS priority
    FROM   a
  ) t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Or, for your data:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vendorid ORDER BY priority, record_no DESC)
           AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT u.*,
           1 AS priority
    FROM   vendor_update u
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.*,
           2 AS priority
    FROM   vendor_registration r
  ) t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```